# How to check whether or not a iterating variable NavigableString or Tag type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I got the list mixed with Tag and NavigableString Type. I want to access only Tag data. How can I check? I want to avoid the following error.

```
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'NavigableString'
```

Answer (score 17):

```
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString, BeautifulSoup
html = r"<b>The Dormouse's story</b>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(isinstance(soup, Tag))
print(isinstance(soup.string, NavigableString))
```

out:

```
True
True
```

Comment: @verystrongjoe please let me now whether my answer solve your problem.